# Error while creating plugin for Sales Rule Colelction

Tags: magento2, coupon

I am trying to create afterSetValidationFilter plugin for the Magento Sales Rule collection for implementing multiple coupon code option.

Core file I want to override Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection.php

here is my di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection">
    <plugin name="Myvendor_Coupons::NewRuleCollection" type="Myvendor\Coupons\Plugin\NewRuleCollection" />
</type>
```

and here is the file NewRuleCollection.php

```
<?php

namespace Myvendor\Coupons\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;

class NewRuleCollection extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $couponCode;

    /**
     * Store associated with rule entities information map
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_associatedEntitiesMap;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\DateApplier
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $dateApplier;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface
     */
    protected $_date;




    /**
     * @var Json $serializer
     */
    protected $serializer;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory $entityFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface $fetchStrategy,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $date,
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb $resource = null,
        Json $serializer = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $date, $connection, $resource, $serializer);


        $this->_date = $date;

    }

    /**
     * Filter collection by specified website, customer group, coupon code, date.
     * Filter collection to use only active rules.
     * Involved sorting by sort_order column.
     *
     * @param int $websiteId
     * @param int $customerGroupId
     * @param string $couponCode
     * @param string|null $now
     * @param Address $address allow extensions to further filter out rules based on quote address
     * @use $this->addWebsiteGroupDateFilter()
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     * @return $this
     */
    public function afterSetValidationFilter(
        $websiteId,
        $customerGroupId,
        $couponCode = '',
        $now = null,
        Address $address = null
    ) {



        if (!$this->getFlag('validation_filter')) {
            /* We need to overwrite joinLeft if coupon is applied */
            $this->getSelect()->reset();
            parent::_initSelect();


            $this->addWebsiteGroupDateFilter(1, 0, null);
            $select = $this->getSelect();

            $connection = $this->getConnection();
            if (strlen($couponCode)) {
                $noCouponWhereCondition = $connection->quoteInto(
                    'main_table.coupon_type = ?',
                    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON
                );


                $relatedRulesIds = $this->getMyCustomCouponRelatedRuleIds($couponCode);

                $select->where(
                    $noCouponWhereCondition . ' OR main_table.rule_id IN (?)',
                    $relatedRulesIds,
                    Select::TYPE_CONDITION
                );
            } else {
                $this->addFieldToFilter(
                    'main_table.coupon_type',
                    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON
                );
            }
            $this->setOrder('sort_order', self::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
            $this->setFlag('validation_filter', true);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get rules ids related to coupon code
     *
     * @param string $couponCode
     * @return array
     */
    public function getMyCustomCouponRelatedRuleIds($couponCode)
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select()->from(
            ['main_table' => $this->getTable('salesrule')],
            'rule_id'
        );
        $select->joinLeft(
            ['rule_coupons' => $this->getTable('salesrule_coupon')],
            $connection->quoteInto(
                'main_table.rule_id = rule_coupons.rule_id AND main_table.coupon_type != ?',
                \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON,
                null
            )
        );

        $autoGeneratedCouponCondition = [
            $connection->quoteInto(
                "main_table.coupon_type = ?",
                \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_AUTO
            ),
            $connection->quoteInto(
                "rule_coupons.type = ?",
                \Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\CouponInterface::TYPE_GENERATED
            ),
        ];

        $orWhereConditions = [
            "(" . implode($autoGeneratedCouponCondition, " AND ") . ")",
            $connection->quoteInto(
                '(main_table.coupon_type = ? AND main_table.use_auto_generation = 1 AND rule_coupons.type = 1)',
                \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC
            ),
            $connection->quoteInto(
                '(main_table.coupon_type = ? AND main_table.use_auto_generation = 0 AND rule_coupons.type = 0)',
                \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC
            ),
        ];

        $andWhereConditions = [
                $connection->quoteInto(
                'code IN (?)',
                $couponCode
            ),
            $connection->quoteInto(
                '(rule_coupons.expiration_date IS NULL OR rule_coupons.expiration_date >= ?)',
                $this->_date->date()->format('Y-m-d')
            ),
        ];

        $orWhereCondition = implode(' OR ', $orWhereConditions);
        $andWhereCondition = implode(' AND ', $andWhereConditions);

        $select->where(
            '(' . $orWhereCondition . ') AND ' . $andWhereCondition,
            null,
            Select::TYPE_CONDITION
        );
        $select->group('main_table.rule_id');

        return $connection->fetchCol($select);
    }


}
```

While applying the coupon code i am getting error like

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 5 passed to Myvendor\Coupons\Plugin\NewRuleCollection\Interceptor::afterSetValidationFilter() must be an instance of Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address, string given,

What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin code should be like this:

```
                    <?php

                    namespace Myvendor\Coupons\Plugin;

                    use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
                    use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;
                    use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;

                    class NewRuleCollection extends \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection
                    {

                        public function afterSetValidationFilter(
                            \Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection $subject,
                            $websiteId,
                            $customerGroupId,
                            $couponCode = '',
                            $now = null,
                            Address $address = null
                        ) {



                            if (!$this->getFlag('validation_filter')) {
                                /* We need to overwrite joinLeft if coupon is applied */
                                $this->getSelect()->reset();
                                parent::_initSelect();


                                $this->addWebsiteGroupDateFilter(1, 0, null);
                                $select = $this->getSelect();

                                $connection = $this->getConnection();
                                if (strlen($couponCode)) {
                                    $noCouponWhereCondition = $connection->quoteInto(
                                        'main_table.coupon_type = ?',
                                        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON
                                    );


                                    $relatedRulesIds = $this->getMyCustomCouponRelatedRuleIds($couponCode);

                                    $select->where(
                                        $noCouponWhereCondition . ' OR main_table.rule_id IN (?)',
                                        $relatedRulesIds,
                                        Select::TYPE_CONDITION
                                    );
                                } else {
                                    $this->addFieldToFilter(
                                        'main_table.coupon_type',
                                        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON
                                    );
                                }
                                $this->setOrder('sort_order', self::SORT_ORDER_ASC);
                                $this->setFlag('validation_filter', true);
                            }

                            return $this;
                        }

                        /**
                         * Get rules ids related to coupon code
                         *
                         * @param string $couponCode
                         * @return array
                         */
                        public function getMyCustomCouponRelatedRuleIds($couponCode)
                        {
                            $connection = $this->getConnection();
                            $select = $connection->select()->from(
                                ['main_table' => $this->getTable('salesrule')],
                                'rule_id'
                            );
                            $select->joinLeft(
                                ['rule_coupons' => $this->getTable('salesrule_coupon')],
                                $connection->quoteInto(
                                    'main_table.rule_id = rule_coupons.rule_id AND main_table.coupon_type != ?',
                                    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_NO_COUPON,
                                    null
                                )
                            );

                            $autoGeneratedCouponCondition = [
                                $connection->quoteInto(
                                    "main_table.coupon_type = ?",
                                    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_AUTO
                                ),
                                $connection->quoteInto(
                                    "rule_coupons.type = ?",
                                    \Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\CouponInterface::TYPE_GENERATED
                                ),
                            ];

                            $orWhereConditions = [
                                "(" . implode($autoGeneratedCouponCondition, " AND ") . ")",
                                $connection->quoteInto(
                                    '(main_table.coupon_type = ? AND main_table.use_auto_generation = 1 AND rule_coupons.type = 1)',
                                    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC
                                ),
                                $connection->quoteInto(
                                    '(main_table.coupon_type = ? AND main_table.use_auto_generation = 0 AND rule_coupons.type = 0)',
                                    \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule::COUPON_TYPE_SPECIFIC
                                ),
                            ];

                            $andWhereConditions = [
                                    $connection->quoteInto(
                                    'code IN (?)',
                                    $couponCode
                                ),
                                $connection->quoteInto(
                                    '(rule_coupons.expiration_date IS NULL OR rule_coupons.expiration_date >= ?)',
                                    $this->_date->date()->format('Y-m-d')
                                ),
                            ];

                            $orWhereCondition = implode(' OR ', $orWhereConditions);
                            $andWhereCondition = implode(' AND ', $andWhereConditions);

                            $select->where(
                                '(' . $orWhereCondition . ') AND ' . $andWhereCondition,
                                null,
                                Select::TYPE_CONDITION
                            );
                            $select->group('main_table.rule_id');

                            return $connection->fetchCol($select);
                        }


                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all from your code  it looks like you are mixing the concept of `class overwrite` and `plugin` concept but in reality both concepts are totally different.

If you want to overwrite the code then you should use

```
<preference for="Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection" type="Vendor\Some\Some\Some" />
```

And If you want to write plugin then can use

```
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
      <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

According to your requirements you have to take decision.

Now, As per the [after plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) First argument should be the class object so in your case first argument of `afterSetValidationFilter` should be `Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection` as `$subject` then you can use the arguments of method If you need otherwise you cans just pass `$result` in the method.

So, in your code it should looks like this,

```
public function afterSetValidationFilter(
Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection $subject,
        $result,
        $websiteId,
        $customerGroupId,
        $couponCode = '',
        $now = null,
        Address $address = null
    ) {

...................
```

`